# Django : How to show form validation errors if form is not valid on base.html?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form on my base.html since I want to show it on every pages, I'd like to show validations errors whenever the form is not valid, the problem is that it redirects me to my view even if it's the validation is false and throws me an error 500.

Here how I did : **views.py**

```
def askProject(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AskProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect(reverse('success-msg'))
    else:
        form = AskProjectForm()
```

**forms.py :**

```
class AskProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AskProject
        fields = ['prenom', 'nom', 'numero']

    def clean_prenom(self):
        prenom = self.cleaned_data['prenom']
        if len(prenom) < 3:
            raise ValidationError('Votre prénom doit etre plus long que 1 caractère.')
        return prenom
    ...
```

**context_processors.py :**

```
from pages.forms import AskProjectForm

def AskProjectFormProcessor(request):
    return {'AskProjectForm' : AskProjectForm()}
```

**base.html :**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'ask-project' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p>{{ AskProjectForm.prenom.errors }}</p>
      <label for="prenom">Votre prenom<span class="form-required" title="Ce champ est requis.">*</span></label>
      {{ AskProjectForm.prenom }}
  </div>
  ...

  <div class="form-button col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <button class="btn btn-default submit">C'est parti !</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I resolve this issue since I cannot user render(request, ..., {...}) on base.html ?

I'd like to return to the same page where the user is while showing the errors validation messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the data using an ajax request(jQuery).
That would not cause the reloading or redirecting to another page.
Also if there is any error in the form, that could also be validated in the frontend.
If the form is valid, then response object can be manipulated however you care.

Comment: that's what I thought doing!

Comment: jquery ajax requests are more agile for background api calls, where UI need not be disturbed.